# Servlet does not get called in NetBeans

Tags: servlets, netbeans

I am creating a site in NetBeans.

Since I have moved to the agent related jsp files to the agent folder, how do I 
specify the Servlet action in Netbeans?

The Servlet does not get called.

For e.g.
I created a folder Agent in Web Pages, and the class/servlet files are in Source packages,
and the form tag would read -

```
<form action="agentlogin"> in the Login page,
```

then the URL accessed is /agent/agentlogin which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the servlet is mapped to `/agentLogin`, and you want to generate a form that posts to this servlet from a JSP whose path is `/agent/somePage.jsp`.

So use a relative URL:

```
<form action="../agentlogin">
```

or better, use an absolute URL, using the JSTL to make sure the context path of the webapp is prepended to the URL:

```
<form action="<c:url value='/agentlogin'/>">
```

Without the JSTL, you can also use

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/agentLogin">
```